# HP ALM Rest API - unable to update Custom column created under Test-Instance -> user Fields -> Comments

Tags: rest, api, alm

I am trying to update custom column "Comments" created under Test-Instance -> User Fields --> Comments.
I am able to update columns which are under Test-Instance -> System fields using same code.

I am passing following payloads -> 
1. payload giving issue:
PAYLOADCUSTOM = "%s%s";

2. payload working properly:
   PAYLOADCUSTOM = "%s%s";

Basically i am able to update Status, Iteration fields but not comments field.

Any help is greatlly appreciated

ALM Screenshot:-

Comment: ERROR PAYLOAD = "<Entity Type=\"test-instance\"><Fields><Field Name=\"status\"><Value>%s</Value></Field><Field Name=\"Comments\"><Value>%s</Value></Field></Fields></Entity>";

Correct PAYLOAD = "<Entity Type=\"test-instance\"><Fields><Field Name=\"status\"><Value>%s</Value></Field><Field Name=\"Iterations\"><Value>%s</Value></Field></Fields></Entity>";

Comment: Are you sure the custom field name is 'Comments'?, can you please double the name, bcoz all the custom field will start with YY_USER_XX. YY-Can be TS / TC depends on the table

Comment: Hi Barney,
Yes you are correct, I was using the incorrect name.

Answer (score 0):

was using incorrect name. Custom names start as "user_01"

```
So correct payload was:-

PAYLOAD = 
"<Entity Type="test-instance">
<Fields>
<Field Name="status"><Value>%S</Value></Field>
<Field Name="iterations"><Value>%s</Value></Field>
<Field Name="user-01"><Value>%s</Value></Field>
</Fields>
</Entity>";


Regards,
Vikram
```